# Need to add leading zeroes to string representing a date

Tags: oracle

I have a string that *represents* a date in the format MM/DD/YY but some dates that I need to insert into a table are missing the leading zero on the MM and/or DD.

For example, '9/6/02'.

I need to add (when necessary) leading zeroes to the MM and DD portion of the string before inserting the value into a varchar2 column.

How to do this?

Currently, the DBA has the column as a `varchar2`.  No calculations or comparisons are done with the column so it is just for reporting purposes.  I will recommend changing the column to be a date type, however in the meantime I need a solution that will work with the `varchar2` column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first recommendation would be to use a `DATE` column type as it is best practices.

If that isn't possible, you can convert the string into a date, then put that in the format you need:

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(Column,'MM/DD/YY'),'MM/DD/YY') /* I would recommend ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD so the column will sort properly) */
FROM
  /* etc */
```

Comment: Using data type `DATE` for date values is not just "best practices"  - storing date values as string is a design flaw.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I'm not in disagreement

Answer (score 1):

I believe the presence or absence of leading zeroes is dictated by global OS settings. I update the "region" default for "Short Date" On Windows 10 and 11 to  MM/DD/YY.  The change affects Oracle SQL Developer output.

[image]

Additionally, users may configure formatting at the session or code level.

**Session:**

```
--Set session date format, if desired, by selecting **ONE** of the following masks.
--ALTER session SET nls_timestamp_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6'
--ALTER session SET nls_timestamp_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24-MI-SS'
--ALTER session SET nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD'
--ALTER session SET nls_date_format = 'YYYY.MM.DD'
--ALTER session SET nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YY'
--ALTER session SET nls_date_format = 'MM/DD/yyYY'
```

**Code:** (Note: Test 1 & 2 are specific to your question.  The others are a list of available date & time format options)

```
SELECT SysDate
    ,SysTimeStamp
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'MMDDYY') "Test 1"
    ,TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'MMDDYY')) "Test 2"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysTimeStamp, 'DS HH:MI') "Test 3"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'DS') "Short Date"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'DL') AS "Long Date"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysTimeStamp, 'TS') AS "Short Time"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysTimeStamp, 'HH:MI:SS.FF') "Seconds Fractional"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysTimeStamp, 'SS.FF3') "Seconds Fractional Precision"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysTimeStamp, 'SS') AS "Seconds1"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysTimeStamp, 'SSSSS') AS "Seconds2"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysTimeStamp, 'MI') AS "Minute1"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysTimeStamp, 'HH') AS "Hour1"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysTimeStamp, 'HH12') AS "Hour2"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysTimeStamp, 'HH24') AS "Hour3"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'D') AS "Day1"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'DD') AS "Day2"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'day') AS "Day3"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'Day') AS "Day4"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'DAY') AS "Day5"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'dy') AS "Day6"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'Dy') AS "Day7"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'DY') AS "Day8"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'DDD') AS "Day of Year"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'J') AS "Julian"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'W') AS "Week1"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'WW') AS "Week2"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'MM') AS "Month1"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'MON') AS "Month2"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'mon') AS "Month3"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'Mon') AS "Month4"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'Month') AS "Month5"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'Q') AS "Quarter"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'Y') AS "Year1"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'YY') AS "Year2"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'YYY') AS "Year3"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'YYYY') AS "Year4"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'YEAR') AS "Year5"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'SYEAR') AS "Year6"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'RR') AS "Year7"
    ,TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'RRRR')) AS "Year8"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysTimeStamp, 'TZD ') AS "Daylight Savings"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysTimeStamp, 'TZH') AS "Timezone1"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysTimeStamp, 'TZR') AS "Timezone2"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'RM') AS "Month Roman Upper"
    ,TO_CHAR(SysDate, 'rm') AS "Month Roman Lower"
FROM DUAL
;
```